# Uniform distribution problem of finding overlapping region

Tags: uniform-distribution

I found $\displaystyle \int_{5}^{15}\dfrac{dx}{22}$
Can somebody just verify is it correct?.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y$ be the midpoints of the first and second segments, respectively.

For the sample space we can take the set $S$ of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
&0\le x\le 14\\[4pt]
&6\le y\le 20\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
which is a $14{\times}14$ square region.

The subregion of $S$ for which the segments overlap is the set
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in S{\,:\,}|x-y|\le 2\}
$$
We can break up $A$ into two subregions:

- If$\;4\le x\le 8\;$then $(x,y)\in A\iff 6\le y\le x+2$.$\\[4pt]$

  If$\;8\le x\le 14\;$then$\;(x,y)\in A\iff x-2\le y\le x+2$.

hence the area of $A$ is equal to
$$
\int_4^8 \Bigl((x+2)-6\Bigr)\,dx
+
\int_8^{14} \Bigl((x+2)-(x-2)\Bigr)\,dx
$$
so the probability that the segments overlap is
$$
\frac{8+24}{14^2}
=
\frac{32}{196}
=
\frac{8}{49}
$$